# Initial size for QMdiSubWindow

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, size, mdichild

Is there a way to define an initial size for a child window widget (inherited from QMdiSubWindow)? I don't want to necessary limit the minimum size or prevent it from being resized, but just to show the window at the first time with a given size.

I've tried to reimplement sizeHint and to define different size policies, but even with those changes the autoAjust call seem to make the window very small (size 200 x 200) when it is first displayed. The window contains a widget with this hierarchy: QVBoxLayout -> QScrollArea -> QLabel. The QLabel is used to show an image with the size 512 x 512.

EDIT: Correct the class to QMdiSubWindow.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **resize(int w, int h)**.
It will not set the maximum and minimum size.
It will just change the initial size of the child window.
Well actually, what it really does is: it changes the "current" size of the child window. But the first current size is the "initial" size. So basically its the same.

Comment: This helped me know what to try, but see my fuller answer for what actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's no such thing in Qt as a QSubWindow.

However, a call to setGeometry on a QWidget will set its size.

Comment: Sorry, I meant QMdiSubWindow. :) I also tried setting the geometry, but the mdi child does not respect the given size (only the position).

Comment: @LuizVieira, can you resize the same Mdi window with mouse?

Comment: Yes, the window can be resized with the mouse, maximized, minimized and restored.

Comment: If you setFixedSize with the size you want, does it appear as expected? If so, you could call setFixedSize, show the window and then set the maximum size to allow resizing of the window.

Comment: Well, that kinda worked better, tks! But now it is limiting the size to the one used in the setFixedSize call (the idea was not to limit resize in any sense, growing or shrinking, just to provide an initial suggested size). I tested your idea also using the setMinimumSize, but then it no longer works (i.e. the size displayed is not the same used in the setFixedSize).

Comment: When you tried that, did you remove your re-implemented sizeHint function?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. Yes, I did remove the sizeHint.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching for an answer, and experimenting, I found this to work for me.

```
child->parentWidget()->resize(900, 700);
child->parentWidget()->updateGeometry();
child->show();
// child->showMaximized();
```

You can use `showMaximized()` in place of `show()` and the `(900, 700)` will still be used if the window is later changed to `normal`.